# How to divide my app into reusable components using server side rendering in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am confused about writing a Next.js application which will render the pages server-side when I have reusable components and `<Link>`s to navigate to other areas of the application.

The documentation says

- `getInitialProps` (SSR) is **only** called for [pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages), and not called for components"
- `componentWillMount` is **not** executed server side, its **client-side rendering only**
- `<Link>` tag is only client side navigation therefore "pages" it navigates to are rendered client side

### My questions

I am unclear on the following:

1. How to break up your application into reusable components keeping server-side rendering?
2. If there are `<Link>`s to other pages of the application, how can the other pages be rendered on the server?
3. If `<Link>`s are client side, surely this means only the initial page will be rendered server-side, so what is the point of writing an app in Nextjs rather than plain React?
4. If `getInitialProps` is only called for pages, surely this means that the page's `getInitialProps` has to do all the server calls for any data rendered on its page and then send to child components, and this must be very slow. If a page contains a list of items, there is going to be one server call to get the list of items, and for each item in the list there will need to be a call to get the items details and another call to get the items image. This is a **lot** of server calls before the page is rendered.

### My application

I thought it would be easier to illustrate my issue with a sample application of the sort of things I want to be able to do.

- My application has several pages: Tab-1, Tab-2, Tab-3, Tab-4 and details pages for items listed in Tab-1 and Tab-2 etc.
- Each page in my application has the same layout, a header area, a tab bar, the page's content and a footer
- On clicking items in the tab bar you can navigate to the other pages in my application
- Each tab contains a list of items of different categories, clicking on an item in the lists takes the user to the details "page" for that item

Here is a graphical representation of my application.

[image: application graphical representation]

### Project structure

All pages use `layout-template` to add the main structure of header and footer and then adds its own content in the middle of the page using components

```
|- pages
     |- index.js  (i.e. tab-1)
     |- tab2.js
     |- tab3.js
     |- tab4.js
     |- aitem
          |- [id].js
     |- numitem
          |- [id].js
|- Components
     |- layout-template.js --- needs data to pass to header/footer
     |- header.js
     |- footer.js
     |- AlphabetList --- needs data
     |- AlphabetListItem --- needs data
```

Below are samples of my components showing how they make up my application. See in some of the components they have to get data from the server.

As they are components they are getting their data in `componentWillMount`, which means that component will **not** render server-side. Therefore this seems to completely defeat the purpose of writing Next.js.

#### `Component = layout_template.js` needs to get data from the server to pass to header and footer

[image: layout template image]

#### `Component = header.js` just contains JSX

[image: header]

#### `Page = Index.js  (URL= "/" or "/index")` doesn’t get any data from the server, just specifies JSX

[image: index page]

#### `Component = AlphabetList.js` gets the list of alphabet items from the server and renders it using another component

[image: alphabet items]

#### `Component = AlphabetListItem.js` gets the item's image from the server then renders it. On clicking on this component the app goes to the item's details page

[image: gets alphabet item's image]

#### `Page = AlphabetItemDetails.js ( URL = "aitem/[id]")` gets additional information about the item from the server and renders fill details of the item

[image: gets additional information]

### How do I structure my code?

- For the main layout/header/footer to render server-side, do I have to duplicate the code to get the logo in the `getInitialProps` in ***every page***? i.e. in index.js, tab2.js, tab3.js, tab4.js, `aitem/[id].js` and `numitem/[id].js`? This seems to go against any decent code design of not duplicating code and instead pull into reusable code.
- For all the data in a page to be rendered server-side, do I have to get all the list items and then get each items details and image URL in the `getInitialProps` of the page?

Comment: Your project structure looks ok, SSR will work for any component inside a Page. Imagine Pages are regular components that are executed in the server in the first paint of your website, and any component within it will be resolved also in the server, unless you do an additional request inside of any of them. And yes, you have to get your items in the Page component getInitialProps. You could consider creating a page for the list item.

Comment: Well written question btw. I don't have much time to further elaborate just now, but I can give you a couple links to look into.

Comment: Italo - Thank you for your comments. I am not sure I entirely understand.  In my components I am making server calls. Therefore the server calls has to be in "componentWillMount" which means the data WONT be obtained server side. So this seems to completely defeat me trying to have an SSR app.

Comment: Italo : You said "And yes, you have to get your items in the Page component getInitialProps."  This means in my "pages" i have to do all the server calls. This seems completely rubbish to me as there is so much data to get for each page. A 
 lot of it is duplicated over several different pages i.e. data needed for header/footer and tab bar.

Comment: "You could consider creating a page for the list item." - doesn't this mean then that the list item becomes a "route". I do not want that

Comment: The question was beautifully illustrated. Can you explain the approach you have used later on, and also answer the questions you have asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all tabs need not be a new page. Tabs can be components.

On the main page (index.js), you can transfer the data you get using getInitialProps to components with prop.

You can also send data to components such as header and footer via prop via Layout. For the logo in the header, instead of pulling data again on each page, you can create _app.js to the pages folder and pull data from here with getInitialProps.

For more detailed information, you can visit this page https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started

Comment: Be careful using `getInitialProps` inside `_app.js`. I recommend doing so only if you have blocking data requirements for every single page in your application. This disables the ability to perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app to be server-side rendered.

Comment: My tabs are indeed components. I have changed my code that in the main top level "pages" i get the data and pass all the data to my header.  I really dont like this design but it appears that this is the only choice in NextJS